Deuteronomy 28:68
There’s a group of people called Hebrew Israelites who make the claim the Deuteronomy is a prophetic book and that chapter 28:68 is speaking about the Trans Atlantic Slave Trade, is there any evidence to support their argument?

The question would be improved by a direct quotation from the group's publications about this claim and what their argument is.

I will take that in consideration moving forward with any future question, thank you!

No. The trans-Atlantic slave trade did not begin 16 centuries before Christ. The Hebrew Israelites are only off by about 3000 years, since the trans-Atlantic slave trade began in the late 15th century.

Historical Context: Facts about the Slave Trade and Slavery | Gilder Lehrman Institute of American History says "The first Africans forced to work in the New World left from Europe at the beginning of the sixteenth century, not from Africa. The first voyage carrying enslaved people direct from Africa to the Americas probably sailed in 1526.".

Chapters 1 - 30 are made up of three speeches by Moses to the Israelites.
In chapter 28 Moses tells the Israelites that God will bless them if they obey him, and if they don't, they will be cursed. Verse 68 describes one of the curses.
It has nothing to do with Transatlantic slavery.
Deuteronomy 28:68 (NIV)

The Lord will send you back in ships to Egypt on a journey I said you should never make again. There you will offer yourselves for sale to your enemies as male and female slaves, but no one will buy you.

"The Lord will send you" - who is "you"?
Deuteronomy 1:1 tells us

These are the words Moses spoke to all Israel in the wilderness east of the Jordan

"There you will offer yourselves for sale to your enemies"
In the Transatlantic slave trade did the slaves offer themselves for sale?
"but no one will buy you"
Did people buy the slaves involved in the Transatlantic slave trade?
Yes, people did buy slaves. There were about 4 million slaves in the United states in 1880.
This curse tells the Israelites that if they are disobedient things will get so bad that they will go back to Egypt in hope of selling themselves as slaves so that they can get enough food to eat. But, things will be so bad that no one in Egypt will want to buy them.

Deut 28:68 has nothing to do with trans-Atlantic slavery in the 18th and 19th centuries for the following reasons:

Deut 28 is discussing the consequence for disobedience for JEWS, not Africans
Deut 28:68 is discussing "selling themselves" which the African slaves never did - they were captured against their will and sold without their permission
Deut 28:68 is discussing returning the Jews to EGYPT, not the USA

Indeed, the prophecy of Deut 28:68 was probably fulfilled after the Babylonian captivity when many did return to Egypt against the explicit advice the prophet Jeremiah under a series of events described in Jer 40-44.
Historical NOTE:
Hebrew Israelites (there are divergent groups withing this umbrella term) generally believe that black Africans are descended from the ancient Israelites.  Now it is not disputed that some black Africans are indeed Jews and have been accepted as such in many quarters.  However, such Jewish black African Jews are quite distinct from the west-Africans who became slaves in the trans-Atlantic slave trade.
That is, the Hebrew Israelite claims of biological lineage ancient Israel have never been established and are based unsubstantiated claims, ie, that have no evidence.

Thank you for the response, l will add this to the many other gathered notes, praying that some seeds will grow to the glory of God, and some will come out from among this cult!

Ethiopians claim Israelite ancestry (through Solomon and the Queen of Sheba), but they live in the north-east part of Africa , many thousands of miles away from the slave trade on the central-west coast.

@RayButterworth - good point that is my point exactly.
